# Vertex OpenGL LookAt not showing

Tags: opengl, glfw, glm-math

I'm using GLM and GLFW to draw a square. I have the following code:

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    // square

    0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1,

    1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1,

};

glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)_width / (float)_height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.f, 5.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");


glm::mat4 MyModel = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 MyMVP = Projection * View * MyModel;
```

The weird thing is right here:

```
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.f, 5.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
```

Right now, I see nothing. But when I change it to this:

```
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.f, 5.f, 0.000001f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
```

Then I'm actually able to see the square.
Why am I not able to see it when I change the Z coördinate to zero, why does it work when I change it to something >0? I actually want it to be zero (so looking from 5 units up to the center point) but that doesn't work for some reason.

**---edit---**

This is with `glm::vec3(0.f, 5.f, 0.0000000000001f)`

http://bit.ly/251TAC7

This is the result with `glm::vec3(0.f, 5.f, 0.000000000000f)`

http://bit.ly/1QUqBZz

Comment: Your up vector should be (0,0,1) and not (0,1,0). Currently your view direction and up vector are the same, so the cross product won't work well. When you change to 0.001f the up vector can be "approximated".

Comment: @aslg That worked, but what does it 'mean' when I change the up vector like you said? What actually happens? I did an edit by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your lookat setup is wrong. Your camera is currently pointing from (0,5,0) to (0,0,0) with an up vector of (0,1,0).

This means that your camera is looking in the negative Y direction

```
normalize( (0,0,0) - (0,5,0) ) = (0,-1,0)
```

Which is the same direction as the up vector (inverted, but that's irrelevant). Clearly your camera cannot point in the same direction as the up vector.

To solve your problem you only have to use the up vector (0,0,1).

---

[image: OP's scene]

This is what your scene looks like with a properly setup camera. XYZ is the world referential (you can see your quad there too) and UVN is the camera referential. N is the view direction, V the up vector and U is a side vector parallel to both N and V. You don't actually have to deal with the UVN coordinates of the camera since GLM does that for you, you only have to provide the Center and Eye points and the Up vector in world coordinates.

If your up vector is the same as the view direction then they cannot be orthogonal and the camera referential is not well defined.

Changing the Center point to have Z = 0.0000001f instead of 0, makes it so that the up vector is not exactly parallel to the view direction. The implementation of the look at function somewhat approximates the up vector you provide to the real up vector. This is done so that you don't have to calculate the exact up vector every time you want to setup your camera.

You just have to specify that the up vector is (0,0,1) and if your view direction happens to not be orthogonal to the up vector, look at calculates the best approximation of the up vector such that the UVN vectors are still orthogonal. Except if the up vector coincides with the view direction, in which case the up vector could be anything.

If you don't understand camera coordinates, up vectors, etc, take your time to look/read it up. There are good answers in SO about that too.